# Is it possible to generate a unique BlobOutput name from an Azure WebJobs QueueInput item?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a continuous Azure WebJob that is running off of a `QueueInput`, generating a report, and outputting a file to a `BlobOutput`. This job will run for differing sets of data, each requiring a unique output file. (The number of inputs is guaranteed to scale significantly over time, so I cannot write a single job per input.) I would like to be able to run this off of a `QueueInput`, but I cannot find a way to set the output based on the `QueueInput` value, or any value except for a blob input name.

As an example, this is basically what I want to do, though it is invalid code and will fail.

```
public static void Job([QueueInput("inputqueue")] InputItem input, [BlobOutput("fileoutput/{input.Name}")] Stream output)
{
    //job work here
}
```

I know I could do something similar [if I used `BlobInput`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22874533/2258903) instead of `QueueInput`, but I would prefer to use a queue for this job. Am I missing something or is generating a unique output from a `QueueInput` just not possible?

Comment: I've solved this, but I don't have enough rep to post the answer right now. I will post it once I'm given permissions to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution at  [Advanced bindings with the Windows Azure Web Jobs SDK](http://victorhurdugaci.com/advanced-bindings-with-the-windows-azure-web-jobs-sdk/) via [Curah's Complete List of Web Jobs Tutorials and Videos](http://curah.microsoft.com/52143/using-the-webjobs-feature-of-windows-azure-web-sites).

Quote for posterity:

> One approach is to use the IBinder interface to bind the output blob and specify the name that equals the order id. The better and simpler approach (SimpleBatch) is to bind the blob name placeholder to the queue message properties:

```
public static void ProcessOrder(
[QueueInput("orders")] Order newOrder,
[BlobOutput("invoices/{OrderId}")] TextWriter invoice)
{
    // Code that creates the invoice
}
```

> The {OrderId} placeholder from the blob name gets its value from the OrderId property of the newOrder object. For example, newOrder is (JSON): {"CustomerName":"Victor","OrderId":"abc42"} then the output blob name is “invoices/abc42″. The placeholder is case-sensitive.

So, you can reference individual properties from the `QueueInput` object in the `BlobOutput` string and they will be populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives:

1. Use `IBInder` to generate the blob name. Like shown in [these samples](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/PhluffyShuffy/PhluffyShuffyImageProcessor/ImageProcessingJobs.cs)
2. Have an autogenerated in the queue message object and bind the blob name to that property. See [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/BasicSamples/BlobOperations/Program.cs) (the BlobNameFromQueueMessage method) how to bind a queue message property to a blob name